# EF6 async included entities properties are null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

Here is the query:

```
using (var _context = GetCommonDataContext())
    {
        return await _context.AnswerSelectListEntries
            .Include(asle => asle.Optional)
            .OrderBy(asle => asle.DisplayOrder)
            .Select(asle => new AnswerSelectListEntryDTO()
            {
                Id = asle.Id,
                AnswerSelectListId = asle.AnswerSelectListId,
                ShortAnswer = asle.ShortAnswer,
                LongAnswer = asle.LongAnswer,
                CounterpartyGroupId = asle.CounterpartyGroupId,
                Optional = new AnswerDefDTO()
                {
                    Id = asle.Optional.Id,
                    Name = asle.Optional.Name,
                    AnswerType = asle.Optional.AnswerType,
                    MultiplierAnswerType = asle.Optional.MultiplierAnswerType,
                    IntRangeLow = asle.Optional.IntRangeLow,
                    IntRangeHigh = asle.Optional.IntRangeHigh,
                    AnswerSelectListId = asle.Optional.AnswerSelectListId
                },
                AnswerDefId = asle.AnswerDefId,
                PartyType = asle.PartyType,
                DisplayOrder = asle.DisplayOrder
            }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

I am getting an error (thrown from the subquery) that Id, and AnswerType (which is an enum) cannot be cast to their counterparts (int and enum) because they are null. The issue is that they are non-nullable (and not null in the db). Somehow, asle.Optional's properties are being set to null (even though they are non-nullable). I am guessing this has something to do with the async but not sure what.

Fixed using:

```
Optional = asle.Optional == null ? null : new AnswerDefDTO()...
```

Comment: why do you think it has anything to do with async? it's one query - to what kind of SQL query does it get translated at run time? Is `AnswerSelectListEntries` required to have `Optional`? What is the exact exception?

Comment: @peter I don;t know that it has to do with optional. I was just guessing. AnswerSelectListEntry.optional is not required, it is sometimes null. The expectation is that when AnswerSelectListEntry.optional is populated, AnswerSelectListEntryDTO.Optional will also be populated.

Comment: yes, so I'm by far no expert in EF6 to know what kind of exceptions are going to be thrown at what time, but it seams to me that you are treating `asle.Optional` as if it never could be null so that **might** be a source of error.  But because I would never do something like that I never had to deal with the issue "What happens when I access a property of an included table which actually is null?" - also the way you interpret the exception might be biased that's why the raw exception might help.

Comment: @peter Yeah, you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that, since that thing is optional, and is making some kind of join, most likely a left join in the database, that the columns are coming back as DBNull simply because they weren't actually in the database.  I would advise you to run a SELECT * FROM Optional where ID = whatever asle.Id is.

Comment: There is no asle.id where clause in the EF query. I just ran a SQL query (joining the two tables) directly against the db and it is working just fine.

Comment: So every AnswerSelectListEntries has a corresponding Optional in the join table?  If not, and you are doing an outer join instead of an inner join, which it seems like that LINQ query would do, the behavior you're seeing would be expected in some cases.  This seems especially likely because its name implies that it is, in fact, Optional.

Comment: yes, you are right. I need to account for optional == null. That fixed it.